# Can Premake propagate includedirs to dependency projects?

Tags: premake

I have a project that's roughly structured as:

```
main.c
premake5.lua

moduleA/
  premake5.lua
  include/modulea.h
  src/modulea.c

moduleB/
  premake5.lua
  include/moduleb.h
  src/moduleb.c
```

My top level `premake5.lua` is fairly simple:

```
workspace "myproject"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

    include "moduleA"
    include "moduleB"

    project "myproject"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        language "C"

        files { "main.c" }
        includedirs { "." }

        links { "moduleA" , "moduleB" }
```

I would like to be able to express my modules' configuration/dependencies without hard-coding conventions used in the containing project. Modules A and B will be re-used in other projects, so I want to avoid having to do:

```
project "moduleA"
  kind "StaticLib"
  -- files, etc
  include { "..", "../moduleB/include" }
  links { "moduleB" }
```

The include lines containing `..` makes assumptions about a parent project structure that may not always hold.

Is there some way for a higher-level Premake script to "tell" these sub-projects "here is the base for includedirs/sysincludedirs"? Even if it involves writing those dependency projects in a different way to accept that information?

For example (and let me stress I don't know enough Lua or Premake to know how much sense this makes), my modules could say "make sure you set `MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE` and `MODULE_SYS_INCLUDE_BASE`" and then use:

```
project "moduleA"
  -- etc
  include { "%{MODULE_INCLUDE_BASE}/moduleB/include" }
```

Higher-level dependent projects could then... set?... these variables before including the dependency configs. (Again, this is just an example, maybe there's a more elegant way to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to defer evaluation by wrapping the project call in a function itself:

```lua
function project_A()
    project "moduleA"
        kind "StaticLib"
        language "C"
        files { "moduleA/src/*.c" }
        includedirs { '.' }
end
```

When this is called from the top level `premake5.lua`, the `'.'` is evaluated in the context of the top level script:

```
workspace "myproject"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

    include "moduleA"
    include "moduleB"

    module_process()
    module_protocol()

    -- ...
```

Includes are then done relative to this top level script.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the export module for premake 
https://github.com/Meoo/premake-export

projects can define stuff that the need to export to other libraries or applications.
In turn other libraries can import the projects that they depend on
It's very handy and the syntax is very expressive !